# "Restriction is applied to your order...", when Coupon applied

Tags: magento2, checkout, orders, coupon

On my Magento 2.2.7 instance, when a coupon is applied in the checkout, the error message "Restriction is applied to your order. Please review shipping details on Shipping step." is displayed for 5 secs and then disappears. It doesn't stop the order being placed.

[image]

What does this error mean and how do I stop it being displayed?

Cheers
Rob

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to find that particular string within the magento codebase.  Which means there is a good chance that an extension is throwing that error.

Are you using a shipping extension?  If so I think it's that.  In which case check the configs to make sure there isn't a coupon based restriction.  Beyond that you might need to raise with extension developer.

Comment: Thanks Dominic, I have searched the codebase and can't find the Error. I'm using the Amasty Shipping Rules & Amasty Shipping Restrictions, so will check them. I'll let you know